# Multiple Pie Charts in Flot

Tags: flot

Is there any way to create multiple pie charts in flot without creating each one separately and having a div for each one?

For example, I have the following data:

- Year
- Sales
- Region

Each pie should cover a different year.  Within each pie each slice will show the sales for each region.

Also, is there any way to adjust the size of each pie chart so that, relatively, a year with more sales will show a larger pie than a year with fewer sales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to your questions are no, yes and yes:

1. No, you need a div per chart.
2. Yes, you could just absolutely position another div/pie on top of each slice.
3. Yes, you can adjust the radius of each pie chart pretty easily.

Here's an example putting together item's 1 and 2:

Markup:

```
<div id="master" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="slice1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: transparent"></div>
<div id="slice2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: transparent"></div>
<div id="slice3" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: transparent"></div>
<div id="slice4" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: transparent"></div>
```

JS:

```
var data = [
    { label: "Series1",  data: 90},
    { label: "Series2",  data: 50},
    { label: "Series3",  data: 70},
    { label: "Series4",  data: 70}
];

function otherData(){
  var rV = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    rV.push({label:"Series" + (i+1), data: Math.random() * 10});
  }
  return rV;
}

var chartCenter = [$('#master').width() / 2, $('#master').height() / 2];
var masterRadius = 200;
var sliceRadius = 40;

var chart1 = $.plot($('#master'), data, {
    series: {
        pie: { 
            show: true,
            radius: masterRadius
        },
    },
    legend: {
    show: false
  }
});

var masterData = chart1.getData();
for (var i = 0; i < masterData.length; i++){
  var dataPoint = masterData[i];
  var angle = dataPoint.startAngle + dataPoint.angle/2;
  var sliceCenter = [Math.cos(angle) * masterRadius/2,
                     Math.sin(angle) * masterRadius/2];
  var sliceDiv = $('#slice' + (i + 1));
  sliceDiv.css({"position": "absolute", "left": sliceCenter[0] + chartCenter[0] - sliceRadius, "top": sliceCenter[1] + chartCenter[1] - sliceRadius});
  $.plot( sliceDiv, otherData(), {
    series: {
        pie: { 
            show: true,
            radius: sliceRadius,
        label: {
          show: false
        }
        }
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    }
  });
}
```

Produces (example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZT6gmK?p=preview)):

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I think you had misinterpreted one thing I was asking, but your answer was more interesting than I expected! I didn't mean to show one big pie and then put each smaller pie in a slice of each pie.  I meant, using the example above, that just the 4 smaller pies would show and that if one smaller pie had a total sales amount of 1,000, then the entire pie itself would be larger than another pie with total sales of 750.  I assume that the total size of each pie could be adjusted, which you have shown with your big pie.